# Give @State private var a variable Array as initial value

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have this `@State private var` which is an `Array` of strings and changes values when buttons are tapped. But as an initial value, I want it to take an array of strings that is variable.

```
@ObservedObject var News = getNews()
@State private var newssitearray : Array<String>

init() {
    _newssitearray = State(initialValue: News.data.map {$0.newsSite})
}
```

What I did above gives the error:

> `self` was used before all stored properties are initialized.

Comment: You could initiate it as an empty array and then do the assignment in `onAppear` or `task`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything in `init`, like

```
@ObservedObject var News: YourTypeOfNewsContainer      // << declare only
@State private var newssitearray : Array<String>

init() {
    let news = getNews()   // << assuming this is synchronous

    // use local var for both properties initialization
    self.News = news
    self._newssitearray = State(initialValue: news.data.map {$0.newsSite})
}
```

**Important:** if you `getNews` is asynchronous, then it cannot be used either in property initialisation or `init` itself - think to do this in `.onAppear`

Comment: Asynchronous is probably more likely to be done in `.task` rather than `onAppear`, since `.task` is an asynchronous API